# Can't upload images

Tags: bug, status-completed, uploader, imgur

Image upload is broken:

[image: screenshot of error message 'Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server' when trying to upload image]

(image is on imgur.com itself.)

Can this please be fixed so we can upload our lovely pictures again?

Comment: potentially related, for the unaware: [Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur is ending - advance notice](/q/395024/997587)

Comment: @starball so probably related to "*Some time in late December or early January, after proof-of-concept work completes*" - what we're seeing might be the proof-of-concept...

Comment: Also on MSO: [Why can't I upload an image anymore?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427930)

Comment: Also on EE.meta: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9994

Comment: From the looks of it this seems to be an issue on imgur's end, it started failing at 9:17 UTC. It impacts Chat as well.

Comment: @balpha thanks, according to [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9994/is-there-a-site-problem-with-uploading-images-to-answers) it started at least two days ago. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda fair enough, let me rephrase -- it looks like it started failing *consistently* (as opposed to intermittently) at that time

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda be aware that the upload support is kinda bad right now. Some sources WILL fail with a generic error message. Just try to upload anything directly from wikimedia for example. So I don't know if that two days post is actually tied to the current service failure.

Comment: @balpha so its definitely broken as opposed to possibly broken? :D

Comment: This is being actively investigated.

Comment: @balpha no, it was inconsistent right from the start. Sometimes it would work; sometimes it wouldn't. It also began (as an obvious problem to me) the day before I [reported it](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9994/is-there-a-site-problem-with-uploading-images-to-answers) on SE (some time in the afternoon before I reported it).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Thank you for making this post. We diagnosed the issue with Imgur uploads and reached out to Imgur for support. They responded quickly, investigated, and resolved the issue.

We should now have full function for image uploads network-wide. Please feel free to point any per-site Meta questions on the topic to this answer.

Comment: Would be glad to hear details about the cause of this, and does it affect the upcoming migration from imgur in any way? Maybe hasten it?

Comment: @Shadow To my knowledge it is a fully independent issue from the upcoming Imgur migration, and it should not push the timeline either direction (except insofar as it took half a day of work for a couplea devs ;)

Comment: Also, think this should have an item in [stackstatus](https://www.stackstatus.net/) as it had pretty big impact network wide.

Comment: Reasonable ask - I'll mention it internally, @Shadow

Comment: As per my question on EE stack exchange, this problem is still not resolved for me. [Link to that question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9994/is-there-a-site-problem-with-uploading-images-to-answers)

Comment: OK, the problem occurs when directly copying a section of an image from "paint" but, if I save that image to my desktop and use the add image button and drag the saved file into the window it works. However, this is an unacceptable state of affairs even if it is a kind of work-around.

Comment: @Andy Sounds like a different problem. Probably needs a different post to report it

Comment: My original post on EE meta has [you answering that it has been resolved](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9996/20218) (yet I can assure you that this has not been resolved) so, are you (a) going to delete your response from that page or (b) attempt to get this fixed or, (c) anticipate that I write a new question that will be exactly the same as my previous question to which (no doubt) it'll get closed as a duplicate or (d) take some other action?

Comment: @Andy There was an issue with Imgur that affected all images and users network-wide; we've confirmed that issue is resolved. From your description, it sounds like the problem you're having either needs support for your specific setup, or is a much more localized bug. Either way, I'd encourage you to write a new post that describes what you're doing that isn't working, as well as what you're doing that _does_ work, so that folks from the community and/or SE can help address the problem.

Comment: You have stated that my problem is resolved and that is not true so, **please can you remove your answer from my question on EE meta**.